# Grouping By Issue In Java 8

Tags: java-8, mapping, collectors

Supossed I have a java class called "Father" with a List attribute (String) of sons. It would be easy to build a: `Map<String, List<String>>` in which the key are all the fathers name and the value all of his sons.

I would like to know how to do the inverse: `Map<String, List<String>>` in which they key is related to every son and the value is a list of his fathers. Take into account that a son could belong to 1 or 2 fathers (father & mother).

I have this code:
[image: First Approach]

and the result is:
[image: Result]

The result I would be looking for is for example:
Son: Maria - Father: [María Eugenia, Enrique Alberto]
Son: Agustin - Father: [María Eugenia, Enrique Alberto]

Comment: Post your code as text, not as an image.

Answer (score 2):

So one way to approach this is to view this as a two step operation. The first step is to build a stream of `<Child, Parent>` pairs, then use groupingBy to reduce that stream down to a `Map<Child,Parent>`.

```
static class Parent{
    String name;
    List<Child> sons;

    public Parent(final String name, final List<Child> sons) {
        this.name = name;
        this.sons = sons;
    }

    @Override
    public String toString() {
        return MoreObjects.toStringHelper(this)
                .add("name", name)
                .add("sons", sons)
                .toString();
    }
}

static class Child{
    public Child(final String name) {
        this.name = name;
    }

    String name;


    @Override
    public String toString() {
        return MoreObjects.toStringHelper(this)
                .add("name", name)
                .toString();
    }
}

static void SonsToFathers(){
    Child c1 = new Child("aa");
    Child c2 = new Child("bb");

    List<Parent> parents = ImmutableList.of(
            new Parent("P1", ImmutableList.of(c1)),
            new Parent("P2", ImmutableList.of(c1,c2)),
            new Parent("P3", ImmutableList.of(c2)));


    Map<Child,List<Parent>> childToParents = parents.stream()
            .flatMap(p -> p.sons.stream()
                    .collect(Collectors.toMap(Function.identity(), s -> p))
                    .entrySet()
                    .stream())
            .collect(Collectors.groupingBy(
                    Map.Entry::getKey, 
                    mapping(Map.Entry::getValue, toList())));


    System.out.println(childToParents);
}
```

Comment: Gene Taylor !. You rock !... Thankx for the help... Wanna go deep with java 8 streams... Next time I'll post the code in text not in an image... Thankx... I'll analyze it more now...

Comment: You don’t need to collect the son lists to a map, just to get a stream of `Map.Entry`s. You can simply say `.flatMap(p -> p.sons.stream().map(s -> new AbstractMap.SimpleImmutableEntry<>(s, p)))`

Comment: Yep, as we are only after the pair (son,parent). I decided to use an intermediate map to make it clear clear how the transformation was taking place. (If only there was a Pair in the standard library so we could avoid using awkward constructs like SimpleImmutableEntry)

Comment: While Java 9 will still have no pair/tuple type, there will be the convenient `Map.entry(s, p)` replacing `new AbstractMap.SimpleImmutableEntry<>(s, p)`.